# Scrapy + python: csv file not exported in the correct order

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm creating a csv file with my spider but it gives me a weird order of data:

**My code:**

```
class GoodmanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "goodmans"
start_urls = ['http://www.goodmans.net/d/1706/brands.htm']

def parse(self, response):
    items = TutorialItem()
    all_data = response.css('.SubDepartments')
    for data in all_data:
        category = data.css('.SubDepartments a::text').extract()
        category_url = data.css('.SubDepartments a::attr(href)').extract()
        items['category'] = category
        items['category_url'] = category_url
        yield items
```

**My items.py file**

[image: My items.py file]

**The output I get:**
[image: The output I get]

**The output I want, more or less:**
[image: The output I want, more or less]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stacked all your items in a single one.
Each item should be a dict of single value for each key, while you're having a list.

Try something like:

```
for cat, url in zip(category, category_url):
    item = dict(category=cat, category_url=url)
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code correction, based on Michael's answer. Works perfectly

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TutorialItem
import pandas as pd

class GoodmanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "goodmans"
    start_urls = ['http://www.goodmans.net/d/1706/brands.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = TutorialItem()
        all_data = response.css('.SubDepartments')
        for data in all_data:
            category = data.css('.SubDepartments a::text').extract()
            category_url = data.css('.SubDepartments a::attr(href)').extract()
            items['category'] = category
            items['category_url'] = category_url
            for cat, url in zip(category, category_url):
                item = dict(category=cat, category_url=url)
                yield item
```